# How to print a number on with HT1632 only accepting text

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I just bought a 8x32 lattice board (led matrix) and I control it with Arduino. The problem is that I can only use text with the library I got on [github](https://github.com/gauravmm/HT1632-for-Arduino). But not numbers, how can I do it?

I'm going to put the code below, the code of the scrolling text and the part of the code in the library that specifies the function used to set the text.

The arduino code that program the scrolling text is here:

```
#include <HT1632.h>
#include <font_5x4.h>
#include <images.h>

int i = 0;
int wd;
char disp[] = "Hello, how are you?";
int x = 10;

void setup() {
  HT1632.begin(A5, A4, A3);

  wd = HT1632.getTextWidth(disp, FONT_5X4_END, FONT_5X4_HEIGHT);
}
void loop() {
  HT1632.renderTarget(1);
  HT1632.clear();

  HT1632.drawText(disp, OUT_SIZE - i, 2, FONT_5X4, FONT_5X4_END,
                  FONT_5X4_HEIGHT);
  HT1632.render();

  i = (i + 1) % (wd + OUT_SIZE);

  delay(100);
}
```

The library code that specifies the printing of the text is this:

```
void HT1632Class::drawText(const char text[], int x, int y, const byte font[],
                           int font_end[], uint8_t font_height,
                           uint8_t gutter_space) {
  int curr_x = x;
  char i = 0;
  char currchar;

  // Check if string is within y-bounds
  if (y + font_height < 0 || y >= COM_SIZE)
    return;

  while (true) {
    if (text[i] == '\0')
      return;

    currchar = text[i] - 32;
    if (currchar >= 65 &&
        currchar <=
            90) // If character is lower-case, automatically make it upper-case
      currchar -= 32; // Make this character uppercase.

    if (currchar < 0 || currchar >= 64) { // If out of bounds, skip
      ++i;
      continue; // Skip this character.
    }

    // Check to see if character is not too far right.
    if (curr_x >= OUT_SIZE)
      break; // Stop rendering - all other characters are no longer within the
             // screen

    // Check to see if character is not too far left.
    int chr_width = getCharWidth(font_end, font_height, currchar);
    if (curr_x + chr_width + gutter_space >= 0) {
      drawImage(font, chr_width, font_height, curr_x, y,
                getCharOffset(font_end, currchar));

      // Draw the gutter space
      for (char j = 0; j < gutter_space; ++j)
        drawImage(font, 1, font_height, curr_x + chr_width + j, y, 0);
    }

    curr_x += chr_width + gutter_space;
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: no I didn't get any errors but the issue is that I want to print a variable int that change from time to time ,the code above is for printing text, but how do I change it if I want to print int variable,how do I change the library and the main code :)

Comment: you mean `Serial.println(variable)`?

Comment: I don't want to print it in the serial monitor, I want to print the variable it in the led lattice 8x32 ,that's why I put the code above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at [`snprintf`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snprintf-c-library/). This allows you to format a string of characters just like `printf`. It allows you to convert something like a `int` into a part of a string.

an example:

```
int hour = 10;
int minutes = 50;
char buffer[60];

int status = snprintf(buffer, 60, "the current time is: %i:%i\n", hour, minutes);
```

buffer now contains:`"the current time is: 10:50"` (and several empty characters past the `\0`).

Comment: so I include the snprintf function in my ht1632 library?

Comment: You don't edit the HT1632 library. That is something external and you shouldn't edit it. What you should do is have a char array of set length and full that with your contents using `snprintf`. You can the pass that array to `drawText` as its first parameter.

Comment: so it is :int hour = 10;
int minutes = 50;
char buffer[60];
HT1632.renderTarget(0);
HT1632.clear();
HT1632.drawText(buffer, OUT_SIZE - i, 0, FONT_8X4, FONT_8X4_END, FONT_8X4_HEIGHT);

Comment: You forgot to use the `snprintf` to add the hour and mintues to the buffer